# android PorterDuff.Mode.OVERLAY Textview

Tags: java, android

i`m working on a framelayout to bitmap and the textview can convert to overlay
the problem is what shown in app is not overlaid by the saved bitmap is OK

[the text shown in app is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sf2Io.jpg)

[the saved bitmap is ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xiYw.jpg)

here`s my code

```
setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, paint);  paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.OVERLAY));
```

how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

You should decrease the alpha of the paint like `paint.setAlpha(128);`

Comment: the saved bitmap is the purpose bot the shown views not affected. your code just changed the opacity

Comment: You haven't mentioned clearly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: there`s a textview inside framelayout and the framelayout can be saved as image. the text can convert to OVERLAY. but inside app the overlay affect not shown but saved image is OK.  got it?